# change button color based on condition ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Just I need to add two different color button but the button need to show color based on the web-service response 
`if status= "open"` green button
`if status= "closed` red button

```
<a class="button icon button-block button-calm icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle" href="#" ng-repeat= "file in file">File Ref No:{{file.num}}<br>
            Description:{{file.descript}}<br>
            Status:{{file.status}}</a><br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this,

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.file = [{
        num: '1',
        descript: 'File Description 1',
        status: 'closed'
    }, {
        num: '2',
        descript: 'File Description 2',
        status: 'open'
    }]
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a class="button icon button-block button-calm icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle" ng-class="{'button-balanced': f.status == 'open', 'button-assertive': f.status == 'closed'}" href="#" ng-repeat="f in file" >File Ref No:{{f.num}}<br>
            Description:{{f.descript}}<br>
            Status:{{f.status}}</a>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ng-class** directive (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), so applying different CSS class to the button based on the value of 'status' (which should be a property of the controller's scope):

```
<a class="button icon button-block icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle" href="#" ng-repeat= "file in file" ng-class="{'button-balanced': status == 'open', 'button-assertive': status == 'close'}">
```

PS: note that you can't bind ng-class (or any other directive) directly to a variable from a service, but you need to assign that variable to a property in the scope